# system.overflow exception is thrown for hex to integer conversion

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to create an array with two integer numbers converted from two hex numbers.
the code will convert the number to integer value, then store it in a array called `GENPOINT`. But it gives this runtime error. option strict is on, doesn't show any error in design time.

`System.OverflowException: 'Value was either too large or too small for a UInt64.'`

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
     Dim Gx As String = "79BE667EF9DCBBAC55A06295CE870B07029BFCDB2DCE28D959F2815B16F81798"
            Dim Gy as string = "483ADA7726A3C4655DA4FBFC0E1108A8FD17B448A68554199C47D08FFB10D4B8"
            Dim GENPOINT() As ULong = {Convert.ToUInt64(Gx, 16), Convert.ToUInt64(Gy)}

End Sub
```

Comment: The exception message is very straightforward. You do realize that the [UInt64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uint64?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) datatype has a maximum value, right?

Comment: The number has 64 hex digits and each hex digit needs 4 bits. Hence at least 256 bits are needed to hold it as a UIint. That is too many bits for a UIint64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For numbers of that magnitude, you can use BigInteger from the [System.Numerics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics?view=netframework-4.8) namespace:

```
Imports System.Numerics

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim Gx As String = "79BE667EF9DCBBAC55A06295CE870B07029BFCDB2DCE28D959F2815B16F81798"
        Dim Gy As String = "483ADA7726A3C4655DA4FBFC0E1108A8FD17B448A68554199C47D08FFB10D4B8"

        Dim x = BigInteger.Parse(Gx, Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)
        Dim y = BigInteger.Parse(Gy, Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)

        Console.WriteLine(UInt64.MaxValue)
        Console.WriteLine(x)
        Console.WriteLine(y)

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Outputs:

> 18446744073709551615
>   55066263022277343669578718895168534326250603453777594175500187360389116729240
>   32670510020758816978083085130507043184471273380659243275938904335757337482424

So you can see that the numbers you want are in excess of the largest possible UInt64.